# Moto X4 - Stuck on black screen

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, unbricking

I was flashing Pixel Experience ROM with TWRP (`fastboot boot recovery.img`) recovery. The OS did not install on the device:

```
Installing zip file '/external_sd/PixelExperience_payton-10.0-20200130-0358-OFFICIAL.zip'
Checking for Digest file...
Step 1/2
Step 2/2
Updating partition details...
...done
```

I decided to reboot my recovery and my phone stuck on a black screen, I had about 30% charge left, the power button isn't working. how to boot into fastboot?

Comment: Have you followed complete installation steps? after installing rom zip, you need to install twrp zip (need to repeat this for each rom installation/update), then boot to twrp recovery. I need to know that you missed adding twrp zip.

Comment: Actually I found that I ripped off my bootloader, now I have to blankflash, I have the blankflash files but it's not executing